# Как организовать запрос ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Вот проиндексированые атрибуты

```
'title' => string 'Курица с фасолью и баклажанами '
'content' => string '<p>Филе нарежьте на небольшие кусочки и замаринуйте на время нарезки и обжарки овощей.</p>'
'ingredients' => [1,2,3,4,5]
```

как мне получить выборку в ингредиентов 1, 2  3 вот так ?

```
'filtered' => [
    'filter' => [
        'term' => [
            'ingredients' => [
                1,2,3
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

правильно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом правильно, если у вас первая версия Elasticsearch и нужно выбрать все рецепты в которых совпал хоть один ингредиент 1 или 2 или 3. Начиная со второй filtred [объявлен deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-filtered-query.html).

Для второй и пятой версии запрос будет следующим [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html):

```
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "ingredients" : [1, 2, 3]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В любом случае конструкция `"terms" : {"ingredients" : [1, 2, 3]}` будет работать, неважно в каком контексте. [Ссылка на документацию](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html).

**Если вам нужна выдача, в которой должны присутствовать все указанные ингредиенты, то нужно использовать bool/must или bool/should вместе с minimum_should_match.**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ingredients": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ingredients": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ingredients": 3
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а если релевантность подключить условно если 5 попаданий то запись в верху 4 ниже 3 ещё ниже. Можно с эластике это сделать. Или уже php работать?

Comment: Можно на еластике сделать, обернув запрос в function_score. Добавлять какое-то количество очков при совпадении каждого айтема. Чем больше совпадений, тем больше score. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: спасибо огромное.